# error : conflicting declaration for uint32_t

Tags: c++, cuda, typedef, uint32, uint32-t

When I try to compile my program first I got this error:

> error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type

Then I included

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Now it turned out this error:

> /include/stdint.h:52: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef unsigned int uint32_t’
>
> /cuda/include/vector_types.h:452: error: ‘uint32_t’ has a previous declaration as ‘typedef struct uint32_t uint32_t’

Any suggestion to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: This doesn't happen with any of my cuda builds as far as I can tell. I can include `stdint.h` and/or just use `uint32_t` directly without issues.  So I suspect there is something you're not telling us about your environment.  Perhaps you should provide a short little program that demonstrates the issue, and then provide the exact command line you are using to compile, along with your machine config (OS, CUDA version, etc.)

Comment: @clouddy, please mark one of the answers as correct. I'd recommend any of the first two answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `#include <cstdint>` and `std::uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Mybe this can help ?

maybe  #include cstdint, but that may not always work or try

```
#if defined __UINT32_MAX__ or UINT32_MAX
  #include <inttypes.h>
  #else
  typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
  typedef unsigned short uint16_t;
  typedef unsigned long uint32_t;
  typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
  #endif
```

Comment: I tried this before but this did not work out either.

Comment: This sort of thing is only necessary if you're using a compiler that doens't comply with the standards (which of course may be true for nvcc!)

Answer (score 0):

You can check how uint32_t is defined in vector_types.h, maybe there's some #ifndef stuff already exists and you can get away just by reordering your includes. I've found [this](http://code.google.com/p/hydrazine/source/browse/trunk/hydrazine/cuda/include/vector_types.h?r=23) version via google but there's no uint32_t declaration at all.